# Which version of Git to use with Windows

Tags: windows, git, version-control, tortoise-git

I wish to install Git on Windows 7.  There appears to be two versions.  I will be using it in conjunction with Tortoise Git.

- http://msysgit.github.io/
- http://git-scm.com/downloads

[An answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849737/which-is-official-gui-of-git-for-windows) indicated that I should use msysgit if used with Windows. The ProGit book which I purchased also references the old Google link which has been redirected to msysgit. I've installed it, however, later have found that [Tortoise Git wiki](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/wiki/SetupHowTo) indicates the latter.

Which software should be installed given my requirements described above?

Comment: Download the current version located [here](http://git-scm.com/downloads) it should have no problem supporting `TortoiseGit`.  The official Git website is [http://git-scm.com/](http://git-scm.com).

Comment: Actually, it was just a tutorial that said to use git-scm.  http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/wiki/SetupHowTo also describes msysGit.

Comment: All I know is that `http://git-scm.com/downloads` is the official website and has the current Windows  binary on it.

Comment: I don't think that is true for the Windows version (it has 1.9.0, while the other link has 1.9.2)

Comment: 1.9.2 is the current source release.  1.9.0 is the current build release.  They have not actually 1.9.2

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/22310007/405017 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/11849737/405017 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/3672272/405017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally have installed `msysgit` with `TortoiseGit`, and perfectly worked all the time.

It's updated more frequently and and integrates perfectly with `TortoiseGit`.

**EDIT**: At 2016 msysgit it is not recomended version anymore in fact now redirects to http://git-scm.com/ , now download Git from https://git-scm.com/download/win

Comment: Was in installed under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git`?  Wasn't for me, and all I seem to have is a shell DOS-like interface located at `C:\msysgit`.

Comment: That was odd.  Just re-downloaded it and now have a more full blown version.

Comment: you only will get all the GUI when you install tortoiseGit. the GUI application that comes with msysgit sucks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, if you follow your second link, it will tell you that you are downloading the most recent [maintained build](http://msysgit.github.com) for windows, with a link to msysgit.github.com, which itself redirects to mysgit.github.io.

In the end, both versions are identical.

Comment: Not for me.  It directly downloads 1.9.0 and doesn't take me to another site.  What OS are you using when accessing the site?

Comment: @user1032531 Yes, but while downloading, you get a message telling you what you're downloading.

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of Git are available from https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases which will eventually supersede msysgit.

See https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/FAQ

Answer (score 0):

msysGit-based Git for Windows 1.x is now superseded by Git for Windows 2.x.

[Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) and [git-scm](https://git-scm.com/downloads) both points to same download location for their binary